# Trusted testers are not able to access chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I have a chrome extension published to testers.
I added one more trusted tester after publishing the extension.
Now, when I tried to access the extension using that tester account on one PC, it worked all fine. But when I tried to access it with same account on a different PC, I got the error:

> Item not found.This item may have been removed by its author.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure that you're logging in using an email account that's marked as Trusted tester?

Comment: It may take some time for the updated testers list to take effect. Does it work now?

Comment: Yes, it worked after some time.Thanks :).